# Embedded Kafka contract tests randomly failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

I am using the spring cloud contrat to test a kafkaListsener of my service.
I use EmbeddedKafka together with the spring cloud contract.

The listener in my service is implemeneted by @KafkaListener from spring kafka.

The contract test I have is like below:

```
    
@EmbeddedKafka
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceApplication.class},
        properties = {"stubrunner.kafka.enabled=true",
                "stubrunner.stream.enabled=false",
                "spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect=false"})
public class EventContractTest {

    @Autowired
    private StubTrigger stubTrigger;

    @SpyBean
    @Qualifier("KafkaEventListener")
    private EventListener eventListener;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {   
        Mockito.doNothing().when(eventListener).onEventReceived(any(), any());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void kafkaEventTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        stubTrigger.trigger("kafka-event");

        ArgumentCaptor<Event> eventArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Bytes> headerArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Bytes.class);
        verify(eventListener, timeout(5000).times(1)).
                onEventReceived(eventArgumentCaptor.capture(), headerArgumentCaptor.capture());
  ....
    }

   @Test
    public void kafkaEventTest2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        stubTrigger.trigger("kafka-event-2");

        ArgumentCaptor<Event> eventArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Bytes> headerArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Bytes.class);
        verify(eventListener, timeout(5000).times(1)).
                onEventReceived(eventArgumentCaptor.capture(), headerArgumentCaptor.capture());
    ....
    }
}
```

when run the tests case, in most cases it will pass, but it will randomlly fail with the following exception:

> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] [ERROR] kafkaEventTest Time elapsed: 30.177
> s  <<< ERROR! [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]    at
> com.xxx.contracts.EventContractTest.kafkaEventTest(EventContractTest.java:122)
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  at
> com.xxx.contracts.EventContractTest.kafkaEventTest(EventContractTest.java:122)
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
>
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] [ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors:
> 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 212.675 s <<< FAILURE! - in
> com.contracts.eventContractTest [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] [ERROR]
> kafkaEventTest  Time elapsed: 30.177 s  <<< ERROR!
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  at
> com.contracts.eventContractTest.kafkaEventTest(EventContractTest.java:122)
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  at
> com.contracts.eventContractTest.kafkaEventTest(EventContractTest.java:122)
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] [ERROR]
> kafkaEventTest2  Time elapsed: 11.191 s  <<< FAILURE!
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations:
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> EventListener.onEventReceived( [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> , [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]      [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] ); [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> Wanted 1 time: [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] -> at
> com.messaging.kafka.listener.EventListener.onEventReceived(EventListener.java:49)
> [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] But was 2 times: [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]
> -> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z] -> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]  [2022-05-06T09:53:52.883Z]

And from the log it is throw by the stubtrigger.trigger() method. Is this a bug of the embedded kafka?

As a result, the first test case is failed due to the timeout exception. the second test case failed as well due to the listener method is consumed twice already, which means the event triggered by the first case is already consumed.

Comment: May we have more stacktrace to determine a reason of that timeout?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I edited the question and pasted the whole stack trace that I have. It just does not have other valuable information.

The timeout exception is throw in the first contract test and it fail, the second is also failed due to it found the event is consumed twice

Comment: Are you sure that timeout exception is a result of trigger not verify?

Comment: Yes. from the log, it is the line stubtrigger throw this exception.

Comment: the stubtrigger can also have the possiblity to throw a timeout exception from its implementation. You can find the code in the class: KafkaStubMessages

Comment: Sure! I would suggest to debug that one then to track down where and why it does throw that exception . Also: I’d be glad to play with it if you’d share with us a simple project

Comment: I can not share the project as its wriiten for a business application in our company. Its almost not possible for me to debug the error as I never reproduce this issue in my local, this failure only randomlly occure in our pull rquest build time(the cloud environment)

Answer (score 1):

To test the integration, I previously performed the following steps in order and got the answer:

step 1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

step 2:

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducer {
  private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;
  public void send(String topic,String payload){
    kafkaTemplate.send( topic,payload );
  }
}
```

step 3:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
  String payload;
  @KafkaListener(topics ="test-topic",groupId = "test")
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?,?> consumerRecord){
  setPayload(consumerRecord.toString());
  }
  public void setPayload(String p){
    payload=p;
  }
  public String getPayload(){
    return payload;
  }
  
}
```

step 4:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094", "port" +
"=9094" })
public class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  private KafkaConsumer consumer;
  @Autowired
  private KafkaProducer producer;
  private String topic="test-topic";
  @Test
  public void test_integration ()
  throws Exception {
    producer.send(topic, "Sending for test integration");
    Assert.assertTrue(consumer.getPayload().contains( "test-topic" ));
  }
}
```

Comment: The case I have is  different, I am trying to test the contract for our application. I have to use the stubtrigger to trigger a event that belongs to another application.

I dont see an analertive beside the stubtrigger

Comment: See if `@DirtiesContext` can help somehow. Without reproducible sample it is hard to help , sorry